# Changing a frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

When a view controller's view is first shown I want to run an animation in which all elements in the view controller slide from outside the bottom of the screen to their natural positions. To achieve this, I do `subview.frame.origin.y += self.view.frame.size.height` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. I also tried `viewWillAppear`, but it doesn't work at all. Then I animate them up to their natural positions with `subview.frame.origin.y -= self.view.frame.size.height` in `viewDidAppear`.

The problem is that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called several times throughout the view controller's lifespan. As such, when things like showing the keyboard happen all my content gets replaced outside the view again.

Is there a better method for doing this? Do I need to add some sort of flag to check whether the animation has already run?

EDIT: here's the code. Here I'm calling `prepareAppearance` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which works, but `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called multiple times throughout the controller's life span.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self prepareAppearance];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self animateAppearance];
}


- (NSArray *)animatableViews
{
    return @[self.createAccountButton, self.facebookButton, self.linkedInButton, self.loginButton];
}

- (void)prepareAppearance
{
    NSArray * views = [self animatableViews];
    NSUInteger count = [views count];

    for (NSUInteger it=0 ; it < count ; ++it) {

        UIView * view = [views objectAtIndex:it];
        CGRect frame = view.frame;

        // Move the views outside the screen, to the bottom
        frame.origin.y += self.view.frame.size.height;

        [view setFrame:frame];
    }
}

- (void)animateAppearance
{
    NSArray * views = [self animatableViews];
    NSUInteger count = [views count];

    for (NSUInteger it=0 ; it < count ; ++it) {

        __weak UIView * weakView = [views objectAtIndex:it];
        CGRect referenceFrame = self.view.frame;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                              delay:0.05f * it
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{

                             CGRect frame = weakView.frame;
                             frame.origin.y -= referenceFrame.size.height;

                             [weakView setFrame:frame];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to animate something when view will appear and then not touch subviews later, I would suggest the following:

- Don't change/touch `viewDidLayoutSubviews`
- Add logic to move elements outside the screen (to their initial position *before* animation) in `viewWillAppear`
- Add logic to animate elements into their proper position in `viewDidAppear`

**UPDATE**:

If you're using auto-layout (which is very good thing), you can't animate views by changing their frames directly (because auto-layout would ignore that and change them again). What you need to do is to expose outlets to constraints responsible for Y-position (in your case) and change that constraints rather then setting frames.

Also don't forget to include call to `[weakView layoutIfNeeded]` after you update constraints in the animation method.

Comment: I did mention in the question that I already tried that! It seems that in `viewDidAppear` the UI is not ready yet and so the elements do not get moved outside the screen

Comment: But oddly enough, the animation does work! Should it?

Comment: Yes. Even if you have center alignment constraints you can change them to move view out of the frame.

Comment: It did! It turns out that animating using the constraints solves the issue. It isn't for nothing that Apple is now recommending animations using constraints. I already ported my animations to use this. Also apologies for the delay in accepting the answer; I had never animated like this and it required some reading. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I did both things in `viewDidAppear:`. It seems that when `viewDidAppear:` is called, the view is not actually visible, but about to. So the UI elements never show in their initial position if they are replaced there.

Comment: Please double check everything. viewDidAppear is called `after` view has appeared, so everything must be visible and laid out already.

Comment: Yes, I noticed. In the simulator it appeared to be running well, but on the device it shows much earlier. The problem persists.

Comment: Please post the current code so we can take a look at it.

Comment: @sha, the code isn't much. I have a method called `prepareAppearance` which moves the views outside the screen (without animating) and another one called `animateAppearance`, which does the opposite, but animating the views. Bot the animations and the setup are working properly, just the time I call them isn't correct. I also realise that the problem is that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is being called *after* `viewWillAppear`, which causes the views to be reset to their original places. This is why it's not working.

Comment: I give up. Without seeing your code - there is no point to discussing this further.

Comment: I posted the code. I still don't think it's relevant, as the answer I'm looking for is the method in the view controller's lifecycle that is called after the views are already layout but not yet visible. But if the code helps, please let me know.

Comment: Do you use auto-layout? What happened if you follow my answer? (remove entirely `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and move call to `prepareAppearance` to viewWillAppear)

Comment: Yes, I'm using auto-layout and honestly I rather keep using it. If I use it in `viewWillAppear` it doesn't work because `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` are called after that, and those methods return the views to their natural positions. So they do change places, but then their positions are reset.